# Get parent directory from file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dev-c++

I need to get parent directory from file in C++:

For example:

Input:

```
D:\Devs\Test\sprite.png
```

Output:

```
D:\Devs\Test\ [or D:\Devs\Test]
```

I can do this with a function:

```
char *str = "D:\\Devs\\Test\\sprite.png";
for(int i = strlen(str) - 1; i>0; --i)
{
    if( str[i] == '\\' )
    {
        str[i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
}
```

But, I just want to know there is exist a built-in function.
I use VC++ 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing a const string is undefined behavior, so declare something like below:

```
char str[] = "D:\\Devs\\Test\\sprite.png";
```

You can use below 1 liner to get your desired result:

```
*(strrchr(str, '\\') + 1) = 0; // put extra NULL check before if path can have 0 '\' also
```

Answer (score 22):

If you're using std::string instead of a C-style char array, you can use [string::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) and [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) in the following manner:

```
std::string str = "D:\\Devs\\Test\\sprite.png";
str = str.substr(0, str.find_last_of("/\\"));
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I think it needs to address `string::npos` being returned if a directory separator isn't found. So if a directory separator is found, then what should be the parent directory path ends up being the file path. I think `string::npos` should be checked and `.` returned if a separator wasn't found.

Answer (score 15):

Now, with C++17 is possible to use [`std::filesystem::path::parent_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path):

```cpp
    #include <filesystem>
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;

    int main() {
        fs::path p = "D:\\Devs\\Test\\sprite.png";
        std::cout << "parent of " << p << " is " << p.parent_path() << std::endl;
        // parent of "D:\\Devs\\Test\\sprite.png" is "D:\\Devs\\Test"

        std::string as_string = p.parent_path().string();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Heavy duty and cross platform way would be to use [boost::filesystem::parent_path()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-parent_path). But obviously this adds overhead you may not desire.

Alternatively you could make use of cstring's **[strrchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strrchr/)** function something like this:

```
include <cstring>
char * lastSlash = strrchr( str, '\\');
if ( *lastSlash != '\n') *(lastSlash +1) = '\n';
```

Answer (score 3):

On POSIX-compliant systems (*nix) there is a commonly available function for this `dirname(3)`. On windows there is [`_splitpath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx).

> The _splitpath function breaks a path
>   into its four components.

```
void _splitpath(
   const char *path,
   char *drive,
   char *dir,
   char *fname,
   char *ext 
);
```

So the result (it's what I think you are looking for) would be in `dir`.

Here's an example:

```
int main()
{
    char *path = "c:\\that\\rainy\\day";
    char dir[256];
    char drive[8];
    errno_t rc;


    rc = _splitpath_s(
        path,       /* the path */
        drive,      /* drive */
        8,          /* drive buffer size */
        dir,        /* dir buffer */
        256,        /* dir buffer size */
        NULL,       /* filename */
        0,          /* filename size */
        NULL,       /* extension */
        0           /* extension size */
    );

    if (rc != 0) {
        cerr << GetLastError();
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << drive << dir << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows platforms, you can use
[PathRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748(v=vs.85).aspx) or [PathCchRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707092(v=vs.85).aspx) 
to achieve this.
However for portability I'd go with the other approaches that are suggested here.

Answer (score -3):

You can use dirname to get the parent directory
Check this [link](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_132.html) for more info

Raghu